# Keycloak SSO Session Idle timeout does not trigger while user session is idle for that configured time

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, jhipster

Our application is created by  Jhipster which comprise with spring boot and keycloak and postgress db. I have set the "SSO Session Idle" time as 1 minute in the keycloak realm settings.

Expectation is keycloak should send logout event if the user is idle for 1 minute and more. But nothing is happening(even no log in keycloak) and the session is still alive. I am able to call other rest API without any issue.

While logging in through key cloak I am able to see following log  in keycloak. Not sure whether this is creating problem.

```
03:57:20,717 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-64) type=REFRESH_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=google, clientId=youtube, userId=8299cea8-8ebf-45df-8685-b37445620255, ipAddress=10.198.140.148, error=invalid_token, grant_type=refresh_token, refresh_token_type=Offline, refresh_token_id=2b031b6d-5ff4-4967-a300-42b930dfc04b, client_auth_method=client-secret
```

Is there anything specific I have to configure in application.yaml or application_prod.yaml for getting session expired event in spring boot Jhipster application ?

I am struck for many days. Any help would be much appreciated.

I am expecting while setting session idle  time in keycloak, keycloak should send session time out or logout event. And Jhipster spring boot application should able to log out.

Comment: I don't think this is how it works: when session times out, server does not send an event to client. It's only when client interacts again with server by sending an API request or refreshing a token that the client will notice its session has expired.

Comment: is your real intention let keycloak automatically clean up session when sso idle is over?

Comment: Hi @Gael, Thanks for your time to provide your input.  May be you are right.  Keycloak server wont sent any event in case of session expiration. But what I have observed, though active session shows 0 in keycloak admin session tab,  web application is still able to execute other rest API without any problem. Do I need to check the token status  before calling each API? If the token is expire then will redirect to login page ? Please suggest.

Comment: It's server's job to return a 401 status when token has expired, so no client should not check token before calling API. If it's not the case then security is broken and you should debug server side to find out why, or maybe the calls you saw were directed to unprotected endpoints (check in SecurityConfiguration).

Comment: Hi Gael, again thanks for your input. When you say server side, is that means keycloak server  or application server? And I need to check security configuration of the browser ? Or security configuration of the application?